# Adjusting for overcounting

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

In my book

for this question:

> How many ways are there to split a dozen people into 3 teams, where each team has 4 people?

The answer is:

> There are $\frac{12!}{4!4!4!}$ ways to divide the people into a
>   Team A, a Team B, and a Team C, if we care about which team is which (multinomial  coefficient). Since here it doesn’t matter which team is which, this overcounts by a factor of 3!, so the number of possibilities is $\frac{12!}{4!4!4!3!} = 5775$

But then this question:

> A group of 30 dice are thrown. What is the probability that 5 of each of the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 appear?

Gives the number of favorable events as $\frac{30!}{(5!)^6}$ because it is the number of permutations of the sequence 1111122222...66666.

I know that the numbers can be rearranged in 30! possible ways and then we adjust for overcounting the number of ways that each group of 5 can be arranged within that group (the 1s can come in any order, so divide by 5! and the same for the other numbers), giving the $(5!)^6$.

However, I would think that (as in the first problem) we also don't care if the first sequence of 5 numbers is the 2's group or the 3's group etc. so shouldn't we divide by 6! as well (the number of ways in which the groups of 5 can be rearranged)? (for a final result of $\frac{30!}{(5!)^66!}$)

Comment: You should be able to convince yourself with a smaller example that you are incorrect.  Consider tossing two coins... one of which is a dime and the other a quarter so that we can tell them apart.  How many ways can the two coins be tossed so that we have one head and one tail?  $\frac{2!}{1!1!2!}$?  No, the outcome where the quarter was the head and the dime is a tail is different than the outcome where the quarter was the tail and the dime is the head.

Comment: We divided by $3!$ in the first example because we wanted to "forget" what label each team had... but in the second example, the labels we were using were "this group of dice all rolled a 1" and "this group all rolled a 2" etc... and we should not forget that.  In effect, by dividing by $6!$ you are restricting yourself to the case where the numbers as they are first encountered occur only in increasing order.

Comment: That was super useful. Thanks!

Comment: @JMoravitz: Looks like an answer to me :-)